# How do I enable Airplay for youtube videos in a webview?

Tags: ios, youtube-api, airplay

I'm using the youtube helper view, and I modified the webview so that mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay=YES

When I tap the airplay button on the player, I get this. In the youtube app I have choices for Apple TV or iPhone. Am I doing something wrong? Is there something additional I need to do for the airplay choices to be made available?

[image: screenshot]

youtube app with airplay options:
[image]

Comment: found any solution for this?

Comment: @LeonBoon Nope, I didn't find a solution to this. Still looking.

Comment: Any luck? I included an extra step of initializing the player with "x-webkit-airplay" : "allow" via the playerVars

Comment: @bdalziel did that work for you? I tried that and it still doesn't work for me

Comment: No - still nothing. AirPlay works from the control center (swipe up menu), but the devices don't show when popped from the YouTube video chrome. I can't figure out if I'm missing an integration step, or if the video player is doing something wrong.